# Powershell, IIS Express, Server 2012, Microsoft.Web.Administration requires run as admin

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0, iis-express

I'm having a strange issue with Microsoft.Web.Adminstration 7.9.0.0 for IISExpress requiring run as administrator on Server 2012.

What I'm trying to do is add a Website to a custom ApplicationHost.config file using powershell.

I've tested my powershell script on windows 10 and windows 8.1 and both work with out admin, but I'm stuck with Server 2012.

I thought it could be something to do with a conflict between DLL versions IE 7.0.0.0 and 7.9.0.0.

I've added the DLL next to the file, but Add-Type keeps loading it from the GAC. Very annoying.

The only thing I can think of now is; there's some sort of GAC permission issue. Which doesn't make sense.

```
# Copied the DLL from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Administration\7.9.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
$assemblyPath = "{Path to dll}\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll"
Add-Type -LiteralPath $assemblyPath

# This shows Microsoft.Web.Administration loading from the GAC. 
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies()

$iisApplicationConfig = $(Resolve-Path "{Path to applicationhost.config}\applicationhost.config")
$serverManager = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager -ArgumentList @($iisApplicationConfig)
$site = $serverManager.Sites[$BuildDefaultProjectName]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what's forcing it to use 7.9.0.0

look in here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\aspnet.config

there is a redirect.

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Administration"
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0"
newVersion="7.9.0.0" />
<codeBase version="7.9.0.0"
href="FILE://%FalconBin%/Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

you could try the full IIS admin package directly 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration